# Laravel: Addition to an existing field data in a column

Tags: php, mysql, orm, laravel, eloquent

Please how do i express this php mysql update code in eloquent

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `some_table` SET `value` = `value` + 1000 WHERE `id` = 1");
```

or

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `some_table` SET `value` = `value` + $formdata WHERE `id` = 1");
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just retrieve the model and increment it:

```
$model = Some_Model::find( $id );
$model->value += 1000;
$model->save();
```

Comment: Here is my update code `Inventorie::update($arrinput['id'][$i], array( 'quantity'=> 'quantity + ' $arrinput['q'][$i], 'cprice'=>$arrinput['c'][$i], 'sprice'=>$arrinput['s'][$i] )); echo "updated"."<br>";`

Comment: You left out the `DB::raw()` part of the update.  That's important, since otherwise it will see 'quantity' as a string and not a column name.  You want it to be `'quantity'=>DB::raw('quantity + ' . $arrinput['q'][$i])`

Comment: OMG! you the best! it works like magic!!!, thanks so much for the help!!!, can i do other arithmetic functions with the same method?

Comment: `DB::raw()` will tell it to pass the contents to the database engine directly.  You can read up on it under Query Builder at laravel.com/docs

Answer (score 28):

The ideal way to do this is to use the in-built Laravel function `increment`

```
$model = Some_Model::find( $id );
$model->increment('value',1000);
```

or

```
Some_Model::where('id',1)->increment('value',1000);
```

The documentation for the same is at http://laravel.com/docs/queries#raw-expressions

Answer (score 11):

Using Eloquent you can write your queries as follow:

```php
SomeTable::where('id', 1)
    ->update(array('value', DB::raw('value + 1000')));
```

Comment: Here is my update code

`Inventorie::update($arrinput['id'][$i], array(
         'quantity'=> 'quantity + ' $arrinput['q'][$i],
     'cprice'=>$arrinput['c'][$i],
    'sprice'=>$arrinput['s'][$i] ));
    
     echo "updated"."<br>";`